# How to detect / localize the floor / ground from a webcam while moving

Tags: javascript, opencv, image-processing, three.js, video-processing

I have the following problem :

I have some markers ( more specific : Hiro , A , Kanji ) displayed on some banners and I have to display a 3D model ( e.g augmented reality ) when the markers is recognized.
Everything's good up to this point , BUT the thing is the 3D model has to be pinned on the ground.
The ground isn't perfect flat neither hardcore bumpy , it's like a meadow.

My question : is it possible to pin the 3D model on the ground wihout anything else ( by that I mean physical things , not software ) ?

If yes , what do you think is the easiest way ?I've heard there might be a solution if I use OpenCV.js but didn't find anything useful yet.

The 3D model is well displayed on marker , the only thing I have to do is to set its position so it will be placed exactly on the ground . But how do I find these x , y , z coordinates ?

At this point I don't have any code to show because I don't even know where should I start so what I'll do will be worth working.

The whole thing , from where I scan the marker via de webcam is from a website.
I'm using NodeJS & ExpressJS on back-end
EJS as template
THREE.js for the augmented reality stuff

What do you think?Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: put markers on the ground

Comment: Hi @Micka and thanks for reply , but having markers on vertical banners is a priority.Do you know how can I achieve this displaying the markers on vertical banners ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may look on SLAM (simultaneous localization and mapping) technique. It estimates the unknown environment while the camera moves. Based on that you can extract the ground plane and attach the model to this plane if the marker is detected. It is quite hard to implement it from scratch but you can use some AR libraries that can do all the tracking part for you.